Align Axis to mesh to make easy to move
I am just leaning Blender 4 and can't figure out how to align the Axis to mesh to make it easy to move. In the screenshot I want the Axis to align so I only have to move with the blue arrow.


In the Transform Orientations panel choose Local.

If the origin is not aligned with the faces anymore, you'll need to align it back or create a custom orientation by selecting a face in Edit mode and clicking on the "+", keep the new orientation selected in the panel:


Do you know if it's possible to have a custom coordinate system?

@Daniel Möller oh yes of course my bad

Great! I wonder why I never saw that option lurking there.
